# Grouping similar sets algorithm

Tags: algorithm, set, grouping, aggregate, similarity

I have a search engine. The search engine generates results when is searched for a keyword. What I need is to find all other keywords which generate similar results.

For example keyword *k1* gives result set *R1* = { 1,2,3,4,5,...40 }, which contains up to 40 document ids. And I need to get a list of all other keywords *K1* which generate results similar to what *k1* generates.

The similarity S(*R1*, *R2*) between two result sets *R1* and *R2* is computed as follows:
`2 * (number of same elements both in _R1_ and _R2_) / ( (total number of elements in _R1_) + (total number of elements in _R2_) )`. Example: *R1* = {1,2,3} and *R2* = {2,3,4,5} gives S(*R1*, *R2*) = (2*|{2,3}|) / |{1,2,3}| + |{2,3,4,5}| = (2*2)/(3+4) = 4/7 = 0.57.

There are more than 100,000 keywords thus more than 100,000 result sets. So far I only was able to solve this problem the hard way O(N^2), where each result set is comprated to every other set. This takes a lot of time.

Is there someone with a better idea?

Some similar post which not solve the problem completely:

- [How to store sets, to find similar patterns fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462563/how-to-store-sets-to-find-similar-patterns-fast)
- [efficient algorithm to compare similarity between sets of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053821/efficient-algorithm-to-compare-similarity-between-sets-of-numbers)

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.110.3089

Answer (score 0):

One question are the results in sorted order?

Something which came to mind combine both the sets , sort it and find duplicates. It can be reduced to O(nlogn)

Comment: You would still need to combine every set with another set, which gives n*(n-1) combinations, right?

Answer (score 0):

To make the problem be simple, it is supposed that all the key words have 10 results ans k1 is the key word to be compared. You remove 9 results from the set of each key word. Now compare the last result with k1's and the key words with the same last result is what you want. If a key word has 1 result in common with k1, there is only 1% **probability** that it will remain. A key word with 5 results in common with k1 will have 25% **probability** to remain. Maybe you will think that 1% is too big, then you can repeat the process above n times and the key word with 1 result in common will have 1%^n probability to remain. 
The time is **O(N)**.

Answer (score 0):

Is your similarity criterium *fixed*, or can we apply a bit of variety to achieve faster search engine?

**Alternative:**

An alternative that came to my mind:

Given your result set R1, you could go through the documents and create a histogram over other keywords that those documents would be matched to. Then, if given alternative keyword gets, say, at least #R1/2 hits, you list it as "similar".

The big difference is, that you do not consider documents that are not in R1 at all.

---

**Exact?**

If you need a solution exact to your requirements, I believe it would suffice to compute R2 set only for those keywords that satisfy the above "alternative" criterium. I think (mathematical proof needed!) that if the "alternative" criterium is not satisfied, there is no chance that yours will be.